# salesforce How to reach 75% apex test

Tags: salesforce

I am at 71%, 4 lines of code cannot be run in the test for some reason.
When I test myself in Salesforce it works (those lines of code are running).
How can I get these lines of code to run in the test?

1. Lines not running, in second for loop
      nextId=Integer.Valueof(c.next_id__c);
2. Lines not running, in third for loop 
           btnRecord.next_id__c = newid + 1;
           btnRecord.last_id__c = newId;

   ```
       btnRecord.last_assigned_starting_id__c = nextId;
       btnRecord.last_assigned_ending_id__c = newId;
   ```

Below is my code:

```
trigger getNextId on tracking__c (before insert, before update) {

Integer newId;
Integer lastId;
Integer nextId;

newId=0;
lastId=0;
nextId =0;



//add the total accounts to the last_id
for (tracking__c bt: Trigger.new) {

    //get the next id
    List<tracking_next_id__c> btnxtid = [SELECT  next_id__c FROM tracking_next_id__c];

    for (tracking_next_id__c c : btnxtid )
    {
       nextId=Integer.Valueof(c.next_id__c);
    }


    newId = Integer.Valueof(bt.total_account__c) + nextId;

    bt.starting_id__c = nextId;
    bt.ending_id__c = newId;

    tracking_next_id__c[] nextIdToUpdate = [SELECT last_id__c, next_id__c, last_assigned_starting_id__c, last_assigned_ending_id__c FROM tracking_next_id__c];
    for(tracking_next_id__c btnRecord : nextIdToUpdate ){

        btnRecord.next_id__c = newid + 1;
        btnRecord.last_id__c = newId;

        btnRecord.last_assigned_starting_id__c = nextId;
        btnRecord.last_assigned_ending_id__c = newId;

    }

    update nextIdToUpdate ;

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though test coverage is increased by using seeAllData=true, it is not best practice to use seeAllData unless and until it is really required. Please find the blog [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149110/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-seealldata-true) for details.

Another way to increase the coverage is by creating test Data for tracking_next_id__c object.

```
    @isTest
    private class getNextIdTest {
    static testMethod void validateOnInsert(){
        tracking_next_id__c c = new tracking_next_id__c(next_id__c='Your next_id', 
                last_id__c='Your last_id', last_assigned_starting_id__c='Your last_assigned_starting_id', 
                last_assigned_ending_id__c='last_assigned_ending_id');
        insert c;
        tracking__c b = new tracking__c(total_account__c=Integer.Valueof(99));
        System.debug('before insert : ' + b.total_account__c);
        insert b;
        System.debug('after insert : ' + b.total_account__c);
        List<tracking__c> customObjectList =
        [SELECT total_account__c FROM tracking__c ];
        for(bid_tracking__c ont : customObjectList){
            ont.total_account__c = 5;
        }
        update customObjectList;
    }
}
```

I have added below line so that, when 2 queries get executed before FOR loops (*which were not covered previously*) it will fetch data as we have inserted it in test class now.

```
    tracking_next_id__c c = new tracking_next_id__c(next_id__c='Your next_id', 
            last_id__c='Your last_id', last_assigned_starting_id__c='Your last_assigned_starting_id', 
            last_assigned_ending_id__c='last_assigned_ending_id');
    insert c;
```

Just an observation, it is best to avoid SOQL query in FOR loop to avoid Runtime Exception (**101:Too many SOQL query**)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @isTest
private class getNextIdTest {
        static testMethod void validateOnInsert(){
        tracking__c b = new tracking__c(total_account__c=Integer.Valueof(99));
        System.debug('before insert : ' + b.total_account__c);
    insert b;
    System.debug('after insert : ' + b.total_account__c);
    List<tracking__c> customObjectList =
 [SELECT total_account__c FROM tracking__c ];
    for(bid_tracking__c ont : customObjectList){
    ont.total_account__c = 5;
    }
    update customObjectList;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added @isTest(SeeAllData=true) and it moved to 100%
   https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000I5f8